# Is there an elegant method to separate a 2-dimensional vector into a diagonal vector and a vector following either the x or y axis?

Tags: vectors

Hello dear Mathematics users,

Is there an elegant method for separating a vector into two vectors, one diagonal and the other collinear to either the x or the y axis, so that the sum of their magnitudes would be as low as possible? Eg, separating (3,2) to (2,2) and (1,0)?

Context: I'm working on a personal programming project. I'm sure I could achieve this with a quick and dirty code kludge, but that would feel... dissatisfying. I'm trying to avoid conditional logic for optimization purposes.

Comment: $(a,b) = (a,a) + (0, b-a) = (b,b) +(a-b, 0)$

Comment: I realized there's an additional constraint: The vectors should be chosen so that the sum of their magnitudes would be as low as possible. Following the example I gave, (3,3) + (0,-1) would not satisfy this. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Starting with $(a,b)$, if one of the vectors is $(c,0)$, then the other must be $(b,b)$ and hence $c = a-b$. So to compare the two resolutions, pick the one with the smaller $|a|$ vs. $|b|$ to minimize the diagonal length since the length of the other vector is $|b-a|$ in both cases.